# Select columns which does not contain value within the group in SQL Server

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a table in SQL Server as shown below. I would like to select id column which does not have `col1` as `'0'` within the `id` group. Basically in the below table I would like to return only id `173999` and not `173888`.

```
id          Col1        record  
--------------------------------------
173888              recorddescription1  
173888      111     recorddescription2  
173888      0       recorddescription3  
173888              recorddescription4  
173888              recorddescription5  
173999              recorddescription1  
173999      222     recorddescription2  
173999              recorddescription3  
173999              recorddescription4
```

Comment: What if the values are all `NULL`?

Comment: Null values can be considered. only need id's which does not have 0

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `col1` is never negative, you can use:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having min(col1) > 0;
```

If you want ids returned where the values are all `null`, then use:

```
having min(col1) > 0 or min(col1) is null
```

Answer (score 0):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select distinct t.id
from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where id = t.id and col1 = '0'
)
```